# Android foreground service is restarting by itself

Tags: android, service, restart, foreground

I am implementing a dummy foreground service (to see how it works) in an android project. The purpose is to see if there are issues with the execution (in cases such as the phone screen goes off etch.).

Here are some parts of the service:

```
   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        writeStringToFile("Within Service...starting \n")


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                startMyOwnForeground()
            else
                startForeground(1, Notification())
        }

        setCountdownTimer()

        // Schedule the periodic alarm to keep the service alive
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val alarmIntent = Intent(this, YourAlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0)

        val intervalMillis = 10 * 60 * 1000 // 10 minutes
        val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + intervalMillis

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                triggerTime,
                pendingIntent
            )
        } else {
            alarmManager.setExact(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                triggerTime,
                pendingIntent
            )
        }


        val pm = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "sensorApp::wakelock")
        wl!!.acquire()

        //register reciever related with power service identification
        powerModeReceiver = PowerModeReceiver()
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(PowerManager.ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED)
            addAction("android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED")
        }

        this.registerReceiver(powerModeReceiver, intentFilter)

        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

            // Create the timer flow
            val timer = (0..Int.MAX_VALUE)
                .asSequence()
                .asFlow()
                .onEach { delay(1_000) } // specify delay

        scope.launch {
            timer.collect {
                storeLogData()
            }
        }
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
}
```

Howerever it appears that the service is re-starting by itself (as the countdowntimer that i have implemented switches back to 0 - though the service is not destroyed - i am not getting any log in the onDestroy method). What could be the reason for this? I have also implemented a powerModeReciever that checks if the app is entering Power Save / Idle mode, but not such modes appear to get triggered when the service is restarting.

Any help is appreciated!

Lampros